# Java in HTML is not working

Tags: java, html

So I tried using java in html. Java code is simple just a writer that creates a text file in the same folder.
Here is my java code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;



public class HelloWorld extends Applet{

     public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt");
         writer.println("The first line");
         writer.println("The second line");
         writer.close();
     }
}
```

And heres my HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> A Simple Program </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

Write
<APPLET CODE="HelloWorld.class">
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I run it in command promt it creates a new text file. BUt if I run the html file in Firefox it does not create the text file.

Comment: Probably means that your web server doesn't have permission to write the file to the directory.

Comment: Im not hosting this on a web server. Its local. I have html and .class in a folder on my desktop. Just clicked "open with.mozilla" on html file

Comment: Is Mozilla asking whether to run applet?

Comment: @Tom As a separate note, applets are probably going away for good, see https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free

Comment: It did and it said error and I added "extends Applet" to my java code and now it says nothing

Answer (score 0):

By default, applet runs in a sandbox which cannot access local file on client. To elevate the privileges, you have to use jnlp with signed applets.